Need for current protection on low current digipot
Context:
I am designing a power control system for a 24v 300w halogen lamp and to do this I am taking a stock buck converter Here with current and voltage control, removing two potentiometers and replacing them with automated controls.
Problem:
For the current control I want to use a digipot to supplement the mechanical potentiometer. However most digipots I can find like this one have a very low current limit through the actual potentiometer/resistors, in this case a max of 2.5 mA. I am pretty sure the max voltage the potentiometer sees is 1.5V which gives me plenty of wiggle room for current draw but as I don't really understand the circuitry of the buck converter and as such would like to know if I should put current protection in and how I would do that. I've looked at fuses but can't find a reliable source that handles that low of current.
Thank you very much for any and all help!
P.S. I haven't attached any schematic as I am unable to get one for the buck converter and the digipot would be a one-to-one swap for where the old potentiometer.

I have now realized that should the potentiometer receive 2.5mA of current there would be a associated voltage difference of 125 V across the max resistance, at which point I believe overcurrent would be the least of my problems.
